# This code tracks JQM page in GA. How can I track the page plus the query parameter?

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-analytics

I found this code which tracks pages but I have query parameters too.

For example, my url may look like `page.html#one?d=firstparam&n=secondparam`

This code tracks the page but I lose the query parameter:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role=page], [data-role=dialog]', function (event, ui) {
    try {
        if ($.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")) {
            ga('send', 'pageview', $.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url"));         // remove quotes
        } else {
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        }
    } catch (err) {}
});
```

The code is from this post: [jQuery Mobile Google Universal Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872243/jquery-mobile-google-universal-analytics)

GA will display the page like `one` but I lose the `page.html` and the query bits.

No code changes (standard GA tracking) gives me `page.html` and nothing else.

How can I get the whole: `page.html#one?d=firstparam&n=secondparam` ?

Comment: jQuery Mobile ignores any parameters after the hash, so `page.html#one?d=firstparam&n=secondparam` is `page.html#one`. The only way to grasp full url is during `pagecontainerbeforechange` or `pagecontainerbeforetransition`.

Comment: Thanks but replacing `pageshow` with those doesn't change anything.

Comment: you're probably didn't use either event properly. http://plnkr.co/edit/gf2gQoptNsq2gwVpM9gs?p=preview you can replace `ui.toPage` with `ui.absUrl`. Check console for results. and `.hash` with `.filename` for filename, hash and params all together.

Comment: Thanks. I can send a new url string to GA using above code with this mod: `newURL = location.pathname + location.search  + location.hash` then use `ga('send', 'pageview', newURL.replace("#", "/"));`. The problem is that GA refuses to recognize the "d" or the "n" as query parameters (even after getting rid of the '#' fragment character).

Comment: I guess `location.search` returns nothing. Because as I said, any params after hash aren't considered _query string_ and are totally neglected.

Comment: Yes, if "neglected" means by GA as a search term. I can see the string being recognized as a page like `/ios_plus_google_old/archive?d=545eb9a8e4b03cfb303ddff5&n=0` in GA using that method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow this [resource](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages). Basically you will need to overwrite the default page by rebuilding it with the information you need when you send the pageview hit. Be aware that there have been issues, as exposed [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133758/not-receiving-fragment-in-google-analytics)

Comment: Thanks. That seems like starting from scratch. I'm hoping someone has already met this challenge and can provide a code sample.